# How to ensure firebase has received push notification sent from app server, without android app

Tags: android, spring, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new with Firebase. I want to send push notifications to an android app from a spring application. At preset I dont have an android app. I want to test  whether the firebase integration is correct or not, which means I want to make sure that the push notifications sent from the backend server are recieved correctly in firebase .

1. How do I ensure that firebase has recieved the push notifications sent from backend server?
2. Is  it possible to test push notifications without an android app registered on firebase?  If yes, how do I do that?
3. I am using  Firebase Admin SDK. Do I need a separate server key other than the service account key for sending notifications?

Answer (score 1):

1. You'll get a success *(or fail)* response when sending messages. This means that FCM has received your message and it will try to deliver it to the users.
2. FCM needs to target your app in order to send notification. If you don't [set up FCM SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) in your app, it wont be able to do so.
3. You just need to generate an auth token. This [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize-http-v1-send-requests) should help you set it up.